How to obtain meat when you have no hunters in the colony?
Okay so I got an emergency message from a nearby settlement and sent all my range combat colonists there in a hurry, without considering the consequences - namely than none of the remaining colonists can hunt. So while all my hunters are out fighting fleshbeasts in some nearby village, those remaining in the colony are out of meat.
What ways are there to obtain meat if I have no hunters present, no way to trade and I don't want to risk my characters in a melee against some boomalope?
(This is a tongue-in-cheek self-answered Q&A, but apart from the basics, I'll also try to share some misc tips & tricks too. I have put way too many hours into this game...)

If you picked a sufficiently large map upon world generation (always pick a big one unless your computer is awful), there is probably free meat out there, somewhere!

Step 1: zoom out on the map and look for red X:es (forbidden from hauling). These are often diverse dead things left behind. There are always a lot of things going on at the map, predators hunting prey etc. You can also click the 'Wildlife' tab at the bottom of the screen, to see what animals that are out there.
Particularly, if you see wounded predators in that list, they probably just killed something. Or maybe they had an encounter with another predator and are now lying there bleeding and wounded, ripe for picking. "Downed" predator animals can be safely attacked in melee (draft the colonist), or if you have a hunter, right click and pick hunt and they will mercy kill the animal with a knife. Killing animals that way gives the best amount of meat, rather than blasting them to pieces with a minigun - the more body parts that remain, the more yield (meat + leather).

Look here is a dead raccoon! Killed by wolves only 1.9 days ago. Rule of thumb: if it's not rotten yet, we can eat it. The wolves have eaten a third of it, but the crisp autumn air has preserved the carcass. Free meat!




Step 2: send someone out to haul it back to camp. Uncheck the "allow" on the roadkill tasty racoon then haul it back! Picking a colonist and right-clicking "allow" works too. As well as adding a butcher job to the butcher table and right-clicking it with a colonist selected. The last one is particularly handy for getting colonists who refuse "dumb labor" hauling, but don't mind cooking, to haul dead animals back.

Here is my main chef Kirk, a hard worker psychopath who loves cooking and sharp knifes... and that's about it. He has the "incapable of dumb labor" trait and yet I got him hauling by adding a butcher job on the butcher table. The colonist will then go haul the closest corpse to the butcher table with "allow" checked.
In the picture we see him hauling the dead racoon back, securing dinner for the starving colony while trying to get past my open grazing area where healthy, plump yaks, muffalos and sheep roam. He better not step into that abundance of fresh duck eggs either!




Step 3: butcher. Any colonist with a bit of cooking skill can butcher - same yield. But more skilled ones butcher quicker. The amount of intact body parts on the corpse is what matters.
Food hygiene is important in the game. Colonists may get food poisoning caused unhealthy kitchens or incompetent cooks, so be careful with that. Apart from cleaning the kitchen on regular basis, using tiles that improve hygiene is a good idea - in this case sterile tiles were used, available mid-game through researching sterile materials. Not only good for your clinic but for the kitchen and research area too.
The butchery area could be a mess without suffering consequences though, as well as the place where you store raw food - only kitchen hygiene and cooking skill affects food poisoning. And well, don't eat raw food, obviously. You can eat a raw raccoon if you are really desperate, but that won't sit well with the colonist.

Here is Kirk playing with his sharp knives, butchering the racoon in the hygienic (hrm...) butchery/stone workshop, next to the equally hygienic (cough) kitchen. (Yes, Paula might have barfed all over those stone blocks just outside the door, she is pregnant, cut her some slack. And yes that's a thrumbo in the kitchen, what's the problem? Thrumbos are venerated in my colony's ideoligion. A bit of thrubofur in your meal is a blessing!)




Step 4: cook. In whatever way your cook can manage, by adding a job appropriate for their skill level to the stove or equivalent workbench. This picture here is with a grill from the Vanilla Cooking Expanded mod (I'm not affiliated), which adds more diverse types of cooking and condiments.
It's recommended to keep more than one stove so that multiple colonists can cook at the same time, particularly as your colonist numbers grow.

Kirk is really good at cooking so he's whipping together a gourmet meal here consisting of the racoon meat and whatever else the colony had in stock. Are those aubergines? Mm-mmm!

Step 5: serve and enjoy! Preferably put the table in the fanciest room you got, so that colonists gain some environment and comfort mood bonuses while munching. They tend to pick the closest free table compared to the place where they picked the meal up. Another little trick is to put your best quality chair closest to the door they'll be coming from, since those chairs will get used the most.

Here is Vera enjoying a well-deserved gourmet meal after a long day of hard work (she does pretty much all of the work that doesn't involve cooking or knives). Grilled racoon with aubergines and ketchup! So tasty, yum!

Step 6: success! Food meter filled, big mood boost, Vera is in heaven!




As an add-on to Step 1 -- if you go to the Forbid/Allow tool under Orders, you have a right click option for "Unforbid All Items (X)". If X is > 0 (and you don't have any items you've manually forbidden), they most likely refer to just-those corpses you're manually seeking. Assuming you have a dumping zone set up for fresh animal corpses, you don't even have to find them on the map!

@RavenDreamer That's true. With the disadvantage that if you forget to turn it off, your pawns will literally run off into the woods now and then :) Which is probably fine as long as the map is safe with no insect hives or dormant mechanoids etc.
